# Gantt Chart on Merlin (MAC)

Tags: uml

In an activity digram when "logging in" do you include the "username and password".  Or do you just leave it as login and then straight to the check validation?

Answer (score 0):

It only depends of what you want to show, both option are valide but if you want to depict data path you can add username and password as InputPin ans your validation will, I guess, have an Boolean OutputPin....